# How to enable a startpage in Shotwell?

Tags: customization, shotwell

How do I enable a startpage in shotwell. I don't like my photos to be shown when opening shotwell. I want it so show an image previously selected, and It should only shows my photos after clicking "Library".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do this at the minute and there seems to be no hidden settings that come to light when using `gsettings` or `dconf-editor` to examine the available schemas and keys. However, to show the available schemas and keys, enter

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i shotwell
```

It seems that `Shotwell` always loads the library as the first item; there is no way to workaround the feature at the moment.

A new version of [Shotwell](http://yorba.org/shotwell/) (0.13) came out very recently, but there is no mention of this as a feature in the [changelog](http://redmine.yorba.org/versions/23) or in any of the other previous release details.

Looking through the feature requests, there is one similar request to yours from 2 years ago [here at yorba.org](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/2503), which proposed that Shotwell should 'show events on startup instead of photos'. There has been no action taken on the request, so I don't think it is a priority with the developers.

At the present minute there doesn't seem to be a way of doing it unfortunately, and one of the developers, [Eric Yorba](https://askubuntu.com/users/13009/eric-yorba), is a member of this site, so he will probably confirm this.

Comment: Let me confirm that the above is correct.  We do accept patches, of course, so if this is something you'd like to see, get hacking!